# Flask and css reference to static files

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I have a basic flask app, where I reference background images in my css file like this

```
.three {
  background:url('/static/images/house.jpg');
}
```

My folder organization is like this:

```
project
    app.py
    -static
        -images
            house.jpg
        -css
            index.css
    -templates
        index.html
```

How do I get my css to properly call the image?

Comment: Does it not work as-is?

Comment: For some reason it's not picking the images up, everything else works

Comment: actually there's like a white background covering my text as well, so maybe the css isn't the problem...

Answer (score 1):

change your css to this, and then try again:

```
.three {
  background-image: url('images/house.jpg');
}
```